# Getting list of network devices inside the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I've been looking through net/core/dev.c and other files to try to find out how to get the list of network devices that are currently configured and it's proving to be a little difficult to find.

The end goal is to be able to get network device statistics using dev_get_stats in dev.c, but I need to know the current interfaces so I can grab the net_device struct to pass in. I'm having to do this inside the kernel as I'm writing a module which adds in a new /proc/ entry which relates to some statistics from the current network devices so from what I can gather this must be done inside the kernel.

If someone could point me to how to get the interfaces it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you address my this query if you have answer : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917950/unable-to-fetch-mac-address-from-net-device-in-kernel-module

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

```
#include <linux/netdevice.h>

struct net_device *dev;

read_lock(&dev_base_lock);

dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
while (dev) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "found [%s]\n", dev->name);
    dev = next_net_device(dev);
}

read_unlock(&dev_base_lock);
```

Comment: Locking is required (`dev_base_lock`) against concurrent updates to the list.

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm, just looks like I was looking in the wrong file cheers!

Comment: can you also address my query if possible,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917950/unable-to-fetch-mac-address-from-net-device-in-kernel-module

Answer (score 18):

Given a `struct net *net` identifying the net namespace that you are interested in, you should grab the `dev_base_lock` and use `for_each_netdev()`:

```
read_lock(&dev_base_lock);
for_each_netdev(net, dev) {
   /* Inspect dev */
}
read_unlock(&dev_base_lock);
```

(In newer kernels, you can use RCU instead, but that is probably an overcomplication in this case).

---

To obtain the `net` namespace to use, you should be registering your `proc` file with `register_pernet_subsys()`:

```
static const struct file_operations foostats_seq_fops = {
    .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
    .open    = foostats_seq_open,
    .read    = seq_read,
    .llseek  = seq_lseek,
    .release = foostats_seq_release,
};

static int foo_proc_init_net(struct net *net)
{
    if (!proc_net_fops_create(net, "foostats", S_IRUGO,
            &foostats_seq_fops))
        return -ENOMEM;
    return 0;
}

static void foo_proc_exit_net(struct net *net)
{
    proc_net_remove(net, "foostats");
}


static struct pernet_operations foo_proc_ops = {
    .init = foo_proc_init_net,
    .exit = foo_proc_exit_net,
};

register_pernet_subsys(&foo_proc_ops)
```

In your `foostats_seq_open()` function, you take a reference on the `net` namespace, and drop it in the release function:

```
static int foostats_seq_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    int err;
    struct net *net;

    err = -ENXIO;
    net = get_proc_net(inode);
    if (net == NULL)
        goto err_net;

    err = single_open(file, foostats_seq_show, net);
    if (err < 0)
        goto err_open;

    return 0;

err_open:
    put_net(net);
err_net:
    return err;
}

static int foostats_seq_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    struct net *net = ((struct seq_file *)file->private_data)->private;

    put_net(net);
    return single_release(inode, file);
}
```

The `foostats_seq_show()` function can then obtain the `net`, walk the devices, gather the statistics and produce the output:

```
static int sockstat6_seq_show(struct seq_file *seq, void *v)
{
    struct net *net = seq->private;
    struct net_device *dev;

    int foostat, barstat;

    read_lock(&dev_base_lock);
    for_each_netdev(net, dev) {
       /* Inspect dev */
    }
    read_unlock(&dev_base_lock);

    seq_printf(seq, "Foo: %d\n", foostat);
    seq_printf(seq, "Bar: %d\n", barstat);

    return 0;
}
```